# VNC with XFCE freezes on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, remote-desktop, vnc

Since 20.04 my headless xubuntu / xfce server freezes the vnc server after a short time, like after 5 minutes or so and certainly when not active.
From the start of the vncserver the syslog shows

```
Oct 11 22:35:02 BS-Server2 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Oct 11 22:35:02 BS-Server2 anacron[93014]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-10-11
Oct 11 22:35:02 BS-Server2 anacron[93014]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Oct 11 22:35:02 BS-Server2 systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.a11y.Bus' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1000 pid=93089 comm="xf
ce4-session " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.xfce.Xfconf' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=93089 comm=
"xfce4-session " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.xfce.Xfconf'
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 org.a11y.Bus[93110]: dbus-daemon[93110]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1000 pid=93089 comm=
"xfce4-session " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 org.a11y.Bus[93110]: dbus-daemon[93110]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 org.a11y.Bus[93120]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.xfce.ScreenSaver' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=93089
comm="xfce4-session " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' requested by ':1.5' (uid=1000 pid=93124 co
mm="/usr/bin/xfce4-screensaver --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
Oct 11 22:36:18 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.xfce.ScreenSaver'
Oct 11 22:36:20 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1' requested by ':1.15'
(uid=1000 pid=93168 comm="xfdesktop --display :1.0 --sm-client-id 2f8228d1d-" label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:20 BS-Server2 org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[93201]: error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Oct 11 22:36:20 BS-Server2 kernel: [115733.127180] xiccd[93203]: segfault at e4 ip 00005602078484f6 sp 00007ffdf326ff50 error 4 in xiccd[560207844000+5000]
Oct 11 22:36:20 BS-Server2 kernel: [115733.127196] Code: 00 eb 91 90 48 89 ef e8 e8 f8 ff ff eb c5 e8 01 cc ff ff 90 f3 0f 1e fa 55 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 08 e8 ce f
8 ff ff 48 8b 7b 08 <8b> 97 e4 00 00 00 85 d2 7e 34 31 ed 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 89 e8 ba
Oct 11 22:36:20 BS-Server2 kernel: [115733.257146] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Oct 11 22:36:20 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000
pid=93208 comm="xfce4-power-manager " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:20 BS-Server2 kernel: [115733.304595] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Oct 11 22:36:20 BS-Server2 kernel: [115733.317064] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Oct 11 22:36:20 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
Oct 11 22:36:20 BS-Server2 NetworkManager[812]: <info>  [1602448580.7144] agent-manager: agent[12c3d6c8e884b7fb,:1.130/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent regis
tered
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[93180]: Registered thumbnailer /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[93180]: Registered thumbnailer atril-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[93180]: Registered thumbnailer /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[93180]: Registered thumbnailer gnome-thumbnail-font --size %s %u %o
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.18' (uid=10
00 pid=93180 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.18' (uid=1000 p
id=93180 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor'
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.18' (uid=1000 p
id=93180 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor'
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.18' (uid=10
00 pid=93180 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor'
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.18' (uid=1000 p
id=93180 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd " label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1'
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' requested by ':1.15' (uid=1000 pid=93168
 comm="xfdesktop --display :1.0 --sm-client-id 2f8228d1d-" label="unconfined")
Oct 11 22:36:21 BS-Server2 dbus-daemon[93103]: [session uid=1000 pid=93101] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Oct 11 22:36:25 BS-Server2 kernel: [115738.266473] panel-6-systray[93172]: segfault at f8 ip 00007f5b3f656b66 sp 00007ffdcdb33948 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.2404.16[
7f5b3f633000+81000]
Oct 11 22:36:25 BS-Server2 kernel: [115738.266503] Code: 25 fe ff e9 57 fd ff ff 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 8b 87 f8 00 00 00 c3 0f 1f 40 0
0 f3 0f 1e fa 31 c0 <48> 39 bf f8 00 00 00 0f 94 c0 c3 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00
Oct 11 22:36:26 BS-Server2 kernel: [115738.861088] traps: nm-applet[93189] trap int3 ip:7f04ad3a20d5 sp:7ffc72c8b330 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.3[7f04ad36600
0+84000]
Oct 11 22:36:33 BS-Server2 org.xfce.ScreenSaver[93124]: Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":1".
Oct 11 22:36:48 BS-Server2 org.xfce.ScreenSaver[93124]: Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":1".
Oct 11 22:37:03 BS-Server2 org.xfce.ScreenSaver[93124]: Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":1".
```

However when the server freezes, I do NOT get another error message, syslog only shows:

```
Oct 11 22:38:33 BS-Server2 org.xfce.ScreenSaver[93124]: message repeated 6 times: [ Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":1".]
Oct 11 22:38:48 BS-Server2 org.xfce.ScreenSaver[93124]: Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":1".
```

And it's stuck.

I am under the impression that the freezing happens when I am not working in the vnc window for a few minutes (like 5 minutes). Difficulty is there will be no error message.

Any ideas?
The setup ran well for years up to Ubuntu 18. I specifically switched to xfce because of the fact that other vnc servers gave problems but now I'm stuck with no VNC - it's the cornerstone of my Ubuntu environment.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem -- vnc works, but freezes after a few minutes and needs to be killed and restarted. it's a pain because you lose your session. I'm on 20.04.2 LTS and have been experiencing this problem since I left 18.04 to 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled tightvncserver:

`sudo aptitude remove tightvncserver`

and installed tigervnc:

`sudo aptitude install tigervnc`

In my case I had to edit /etc/vnc.conf since the defaults didn't work for me, but YMMV.

After 10 minutes, no freezing, and the xfce4 windows are now drawn properly with their window borders and controls.

Comment: That worked for me on Xubuntu 20.04. It seems that tightvnc is too old.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**:

```
Oct 11 22:38:33 BS-Server2 org.xfce.ScreenSaver[93124]: message repeated 6 times: [ Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":1".]
```

The headless server tries to execute a (**doh**!) screensaver which is useless (its a headless server), and then the system waits for the screensaver to exit, and this will fail. I can't tell you exactly what happens, but the screensaver properly will not run, yet the server still waits for the exit event, which never occurs.

**The solution**:
Disable the screensaver on the headless unit and you'll be just fine. Restart the headless vncserver, connect via VNC and disable the screensaver.

Answer (score 0):

I too have have lots of trouble getting remote access with Ubuntu 20.04 (My base system is Xubuntu and thus is XFCE by default).  Using a connection as noted in the xrdp.ini file as

```
[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

-----------the above fails  ---------------

```
A connection using Xorg - the xrdp.ini definition:

[Xorg]
name=Xorg
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
code=20

----------- finally worked HOWEVER  ------------
```

The primary system user ID is logged on the console.  You cannot remote into that ID until the primary system user ID logs out of the system console.

Comment: I do not have xrdp installed - I could install it but I am using VNC over SSH so I am not sure how xrdp would interact with that.

Comment: Point is - VNC works but it sort of just dies after 5 minutes. Are those the same symptons / problems you have?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have created a small script that kills all Xvnc processes and related locks and kicks off the vnc process again.
It's ugly but works

```
killall Xvnc4
sudo rm -r /tmp/.X*
exec ./vncstart1680
```

the last one being:

```
#!/bin/sh
#echo resetting keyboard..
#gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/layouts --type List --list
-type String [aa]
echo starting vnc X session..
vncserver -geometry 1680x1050 -depth 24 -localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Studio 20.04LTS, this error is not appeard, but on Ubuntu Studio 22.04LTS, it appears with xfce4.
Finally, I remove screen saver:
sudo apt remove xfce4-screensaver
and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Go to "Settings->Session and Startup" and disable:

- Power Manager
- Printers
- Blueman (if you dont use bluethooth)
- ...

Restart VNC session

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the same as your other answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1372541/348964